# Laravel using wrong table for registration and returns "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, model-view-controller

What I want to do is change where laravel looks for the email and password for registration. Instead of having it in the users table, I have it in a logins table. But even when I change the code in the config/auth.php file it still gives me an error as below:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in
> 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where
> `email` = test@gmail.com)

logins migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateLoginsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('logins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('logins');
    }
}
```

users migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', 45);
            $table->mediumText('address');
            $table->string('irdNum');
            $table->integer('phone');
            $table->bigInteger('loginID')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('users', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('loginID')->references('id')->on('logins')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Login model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Login extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
  

   * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

User model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'address',
        'irdNum',
        'phone',
        'logInID'
    ];
}
```

RegisteredUserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Login;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;

class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the registration view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'address' => 'required|string|max:500',
            'irdNum' => 'required|string|max:12',
            'phone' => 'required|string|max:16',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $login = Login::create([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
        ]);

        $login->save();


        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'address' => $request->address,
            'irdNum' => $request->irdNum,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'loginID' => $login->id
        ]);

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}
```

According to two stackoverflow posts I found, Laravel uses the model you choose to provide in config/auth.php. So I went to that file and changed all occurrences of users with logins.

config/auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'logins',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'logins',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'logins',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'logins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Login::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'logins' => [
            'provider' => 'logins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

As seen in the error, it seems to still be looking at the users table for email. I am not why that is happening as I have set everything that was `users` to `logins`

Thank you for any future responses, its much appreciated!

Comment: Given your changed code looks fine, and you changed the config files, did you clear cache? If not, you can do that `php artisan optimize` to optimize everything, or just run `php artisan config:cache` for the cache alone. Try this before attempting to remake whatever you have done.

Comment: It turns out the issue was with my validation. For the email validation, I said unique:users because I forgot to change it to unique:logins so it was searching the users table for a email. Thank you for this comment though!

Comment: Ah, such a tiny error. I'm glad your problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

I just remember the [medium article](https://medium.com/@boolfalse/laravel-multi-auth-using-different-tables-part-2-admin-authentication-37d33420ab3b), which I've written 2 years ago. There I've created separate table for other users (like admins). I think that's similar to your task (at least for "config/auth.php" management), but anyway that was for older Laravel version projects, and specifically your question is little bit different.

So return back to your question, I'll suggest you to do these steps:

1. Create new **app/Models/Login.php** model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class Login extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

2. Change default **app/Models/User.php** (basically it will extend the "Model" instead of "Authenticable") and make that as a simple model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];
}
```

3. This is the **config/auth.php**:

```
<?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'logins',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'logins',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'logins',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'logins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Login::class,
        ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'logins' => [
            'provider' => 'logins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
    'password_timeout' => 10800,
];
```

4. Manually create a new **database/migrations/202108200241_create_logins_table.php** migration file, or run "php artisan make:migration create_logins_table":

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateLoginsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('logins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('logins');
    }
}
```

5. This is the **app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Login;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $fields = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string|unique:logins,email',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed',
        ]);

        Login::create([
            'name' => $fields['name'],
            'email' => $fields['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($fields['password']),
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => "Successfully registered.",
        ], 201);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $fields = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $login = Login::where('email', $fields['email'])->first();

        if(!$login || !Hash::check($fields['password'], $login->password)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => "Bad credentials!",
            ], 401);
        }

        // FOR SANCTUM
        // argument of "createToken" method could be anything
        // $token = $login->createToken(config('app.key'))->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => "Successfully logged in.",
            // 'token' => $token, // FOR SANCTUM
        ], 201);
    }

    // FOR SANCTUM
    //    public function logout(Request $request)
    //    {
    //        auth()->user()->tokens()->delete();
    //
    //        return response()->json([
    //            'success' => true,
    //            'message' => "Logged out.",
    //        ], 201); // or 204
    //    }
}
```

6. If you have already default Laravel auth system installed (I'll provide the commands for that below)

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm i
npm run dev
npm run dev
```

Then you need to change **app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php** as well like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\Login;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:logins'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return Login::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT

7. Now you can

> change/add/remove all the fields you want in models;
>
> migrations for Login & User entities;
>
> controller's logic (RegisteredUserController@registered() method for your case) and returns;

8. Refresh caches by running "php artisan config:cache" (also "php artisan optimize" for Laravel v8).
9. Create a new "logins" table by running "php artisan migrate".
10. As you could assume, I've tested this with Web and SanctumAPI auth as well (which is in comments, and you can use them for later). So enjoy!

Comment: I appreciate this a lot, but the issue was with the fact that I was looking for a unique email in users table instead of the logins table hence it searching the users table even after changing everything in the config file.